# A gnuplottex filename issue

Tags: gnuplottex

I wanted to reproduce an animation file on my system (Ubuntu 16.04) from

http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/animated-distributions.tex

The downloaded .PDF file shows up OK (so I think my acroread is OK), but if I recompile the .tex on my computer, the curves, shaded areas etc. are not displayed, the rest works fine.

I found warnings like

```
Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `animatedMWE.52.table' not found.
```

I do have file `animatedMWE.52.gnuplot` so I guess that some naming convention has changed, but cannot find out how to fix it. Any idea?

Comment: You have to run `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option and you need to have `gnuplot` installed, of course

Comment: gnuplot was installed, it produced the files I mentioned. The -shell-escape really solved the problem, thanks. Does it have any side effects, on the rest of my document, or I may set it as default? (In my package making animation is a rarely used option, the rest does not want it.)

Comment: `-shell-escape` is not secure, as you may launch any program with it. So it's better to use it only when really necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to produce the animations, you need to run `pdflatex` (or other engine) with `-shell-escape` turned on; from the command line it's

```
pdflatex -shell-escape animated-distributions.tex
```

Check your front-end for how to enable it.

With this option, `gnuplot` can be called from inside the LaTeX run.

Beware that it's not recommendable to have the option turned on at all time, because *any* program can be run. Enable it only when really necessary.